# How to use aws-encryption-sdk with a named profile session in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, boto3, amazon-kms

I've got a simple script that uses boto3 to pull a dynamoDB table. I then need to use aws-encryption-sdk to decrypt an entry (Can't just use kms with boto3 since it was encrypted with aws-encryption-sdk)

My problem is that I'm using a named profile for boto3 to pull creds, but I can't seem to pass this session on to the AWS encryption sdk. If I paste the raw environment variables into my CLI session, then it all works though.

Is there a way for me to set my environment variables with my active boto3 session so that the aws sdk will use them?

Comment: You can set env variables in python with `os.environ['AWS_PROFILE'] = 'myprofile'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems aws_encryption_sdk wants a `botocore_session=` parameter passed to it, which is not really clear in the docs imo.

```
import boto3
import base64
import aws_encryption_sdk
from aws_encryption_sdk.identifiers import CommitmentPolicy
import botocore.session

botocore_session = botocore.session.get_session()

REGION = "us-west-2"
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='admin', region_name=REGION, botocore_session=botocore_session)

ciphertext = 'very encrypted text'

client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient(commitment_policy=CommitmentPolicy.FORBID_ENCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT)
kms_prime_key = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(
    key_ids=['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789012:key/1234-acb-ffff-22222-4444'], botocore_session = botocore_session
    )
my_ciphertext, encryptor_header = client.decrypt(
    source=base64.b64decode(ciphertext),
    key_provider=kms_prime_key
)
plaintext_pass = my_ciphertext.decode("utf-8")
print(plaintext_pass)
```