# Using aws encryption SDK try to encrypt the files but getting error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, python-2.7, aws-sdk

```
import aws_encryption_sdk
from aws_encryption_sdk.identifiers import CommitmentPolicy

client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient(commitment_policy=CommitmentPolicy.FORBID_ENCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT
)
kms_key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(key_ids=['arn:aws:kms:ap-south-1:588105036995:key/ad1e065c-b51c-76'])
my_plaintext = 'D:\\test-2\\u_in220819.log'
my_ciphertext, encryptor_header = client.encrypt(
    source=my_plaintext,
    key_provider=kms_key_provider
)
```

"""
#-----------------------------
#Am getting below error.
'''
return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
response = handler(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 105, in handler
return self.sign(operation_name, request)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\signers.py", line 189, in sign
auth.add_auth(request)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\botocore\auth.py", line 418, in add_auth
raise NoCredentialsError()
on  botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

```
#Anyone who can give me pointers how to fix it?
"""
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am trying to encrypt the files using AWS encryption SDK  in python But getting the error on the below line.,
Below Error:
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Comment: Have you tried creating a botocore session and passing it to the initializer of `StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider`, as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68991469)?

Comment: i have created one user called admin in AWS KMS IAM and mapped that in ARN key, but still i am getting bellow error, Can you please guide me what i have to mention here("session = boto3.Session(profile_name='admin', region_name=REGION, botocore_session=botocore_session)")

Becouse i am getting below error:

Exception has occurred: ProfileNotFound
The config profile (admin) could not be found
  File "D:\Python SDK\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='admin', region_name=REGION, botocore_session=botocore_session)